# How do I catch exceptions from within Action<T> or containing an anonymous method in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, lambda, error-handling

I'm trying to create a global exception method similar to this so I can display Exceptions and any data that may have been captured before the exception

```
public class ServiceResponse<T> {
   public T Data {get;set;}
   public List<Exception> Errors {get;set;}
}

public static ServiceResponse<T> GetServiceResponse<T>(this ServiceResponse<T> response, Action<T> action)  
    {
        try
        {
           action(response.Data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (response.Errors == null)
            {
                response.Errors = new List<Error>();
            }
            response.Errors.Add(ex);
        }
        return response;

    }
```

It would be called like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(myTask1, myTask2).ContinueWith(t =>{ /*this is needed */ });
var response = new ServiceResponse<myData>();
response = response.GetServiceResponse(async r =>
                {
                    var info= await myTask1;
                    r.Status= info.status;
                    r.Timeout = info.Timout;
                })
           .GetServiceResponse(async r => { r.Hybrid = await myTask2; });
```

The problem is when Task1 or Task2 has an exception, it never gets caught in the catch in the method GetServiceResponse.

Comment: It should be quite a red flag that you have an "action" that is actually a `Func`, not an `Action`, and that your delegate returns a value that you just drop on the floor.  Any time you're just dropping values on the floor there's a good chance something is wrong there, as is the case here.

Comment: the Func<k,t> was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to capture the Exception by passing the task as a separate parameter then check the **IsFaulted** Property:

```
public static ServiceResponse<T> GetServiceResponse<T, K>(this ServiceResponse<T> response, Action<T, Task<K>> action, Task<K> task) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            if (!task.IsFaulted)
            {
                action(response.Data, task);

            }
            else
            {
                if (response.Errors == null)
                {
                    response.Errors = new List<Error>();
                }
                if (task.Exception != null && task.Exception.InnerException != null)
                {
                    throw task.Exception.InnerException;
                }
                throw new Exception("Faulted");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (response.Errors == null)
            {
                response.Errors = new List<Exception>();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            response.Errors.Add(ex);
        }
        return response;

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to pass in the `Task` like this.  The method you're passing *returns the `Task`*.  Having that method accept a `Task` as a parameter doesn't make any sense for that method, nor is it able to provide the results of its execution through that task, given how you've constructed this.  You're code hasn't given you means of performing an action when `action` returns a faulted `Task`, because you're still not actually observing that `Task`, but rather still dropping it on the floor.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the method doesn't throw an exception.  It returns a `Task` that eventually ends up in a `Faulted` state.

If you want to handle asynchronous methods you'll want to create an additional overload of your method where the delegate returns a `Task` (and another that returns a `Task<T>`) so that you can both catch any exceptions that the method throws, but also add a continuation to handle any exceptions stored in the resulting `Task`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Do I try changing the return from Task<ServiceResponse<T>> to Task<T> ? or Action<T> to Task<Action<T>> ?

Comment: @Brian Like I said in my answer, you'll need to accept a delegate that returns a `Task`, currently your delegate can return *anything*, and you ignore that return value, whether it's a `Task` or not.